# ORACLE PLS-00103:, ORA-06550: := . ( @ % ;

Tags: oracle, procedure

I've got a problem with procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SOLVER AS 

IS_ACTIVE "Parameter"."Value"%TYPE;  

BEGIN

  
  BEGIN
  SELECT "Value" INTO IS_ACTIVE  from "Parameter"  WHERE "Name" = 'ARCHIVER';
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IS_ACTIVE:='OFF';
  END;
```

When I try to run it, I gets an Error:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Version 3.2.09
Main Build 09-30

Comment: I must admit, I don't see any mistake, except for the missing `END;` to end the procedure (which you may just not be showing). It is weird to see that Oracle reorting the error in **line 3**, though.

Comment: The version you are showing is not the Oracle version by the way. It is probably the version of Oracle SQL Developer, if that is the tool you are using. You get the Oracle version with `SELECT banner_full FROM v$version;`.

Comment: You have two `BEGIN` statements and only one `END;`. Remove a `BEGIN` and it will work. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4269d9aa86df21cc754a4441b869726)

Comment: There is a lot of other code, that;s why 1st BEGIN is in the code [without END bcs its on the end of long code ;) ), IMO there is something wrong with 3rd line of the code

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be coming from the snippet of code you've shown. I'd guess you're running this as a script and have multiple statements, and it's coming from a different one . Or perhaps more likely it's coming from a block you're using to *call* this procedure, not from this `create` statement at all. Please edit the question to include exactly what you are executing when you actually get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message strongly suggests you are getting the error when you call the procedure, not when you create it (and you did refer to 'when I try to run it'); so you are doing this:

```
begin
  solver
end;
/
```

which generates exactly that error.

If you add a semicolon it will work:

```
begin
  solver;
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb35fef980125b0e271f2f05810e169c)

Comment: thanks, stupid mistake